# Regular expression negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

In my home directory I have a folder drupal-6.14 that contains the Drupal platform.

From this directory I use the following command:

```
find drupal-6.14 -type f -iname '*' | grep -P 'drupal-6.14/(?!sites(?!/all|/default)).*' | xargs tar -czf drupal-6.14.tar.gz
```

What this command does is gzips the folder *drupal-6.14*, excluding all subfolders of *drupal-6.14/sites/* **except sites/all and sites/default**, which it includes.

My question is on the regular expression:

```
grep -P 'drupal-6.14/(?!sites(?!/all|/default)).*'
```

The expression **works** to exclude all the folders I want excluded, but I don't quite understand why.

It is a common task using regular expressions to

> Match all strings, except those that **don't** contain subpattern x. Or in other words, negating a subpattern.

I (think) I understand that the general strategy to solve these problems is the use of negative lookaheads, but I've never understood to a satisfactory level how positive and negative look(ahead/behind)s work.

Over the years, I've read many websites on them. The PHP and Python regex manuals, other pages like http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and so forth, but I've never **really** had a solid understanding of them.

Could someone explain, how this is working, and perhaps provide some similar examples that would do similar things?

-- Update One:

Regarding Andomar's response: can a double negative lookahead be more succinctly expressed as a single positive lookahead statement:

i.e Is:

```
'drupal-6.14/(?!sites(?!/all|/default)).*'
```

equivalent to:

```
'drupal-6.14/(?=sites(?:/all|/default)).*'
```

???

-- Update Two:

As per @andomar and @alan moore - you can't interchange double negative lookahead for positive lookahead.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

A negative lookahead says, at this position, the following regex can not match.

Let's take a simplified example:

```
a(?!b(?!c))

a      Match: (?!b) succeeds
ac     Match: (?!b) succeeds
ab     No match: (?!b(?!c)) fails
abe    No match: (?!b(?!c)) fails
abc    Match: (?!b(?!c)) succeeds
```

The last example is a **double negation**: it allows `b` followed by `c`.  The nested negative lookahead becomes a positive lookahead: the `c` should be present.

In each example, only the `a` is matched.  The lookahead is only a condition, and does not add to the matched text.

Comment: If a nested negative lookahead ("double negative lookahead") can become a positive lookahead, is it possible to state an equivalent in positive lookahead form?

i.e:

(a) What would be the positive lookahead form of my double negative lookahead drupal "'drupal-6.14/(?!sites(?!/all|/default)).*'" example?

Would it be: 'drupal-6.14/(?=sites/all|default).* ???

(b) What would be the positive lookahead form of your double negative lookahead "(!?b(?!c))" example?

Comment: @willieseabrook: Don't think so, only part of the lookahead is double negative, so you can't replace the whole with a positive one

Comment: i'd been having an issue with negative lookahead and your statement "at this position" is what clarified what i was doing wrong. thanks.

Comment: Any idea why this does not work in R.  I get Error in grep("a(?!b(?!c))", "a") Invalid regex

Answer (score 15):

Lookarounds can be nested.

So this regex matches "drupal-6.14/" that is **not** followed by "sites" that is **not** followed by "/all" or "/default".

Confusing? Using different words, we can say it matches "drupal-6.14/" that is **not** followed by "sites" **unless** that is further followed by "/all" or "/default"

Comment: Thanks for this. And *yes* I do still find it confusing LOL.

I think you're quote of "not followed by sites *unless* followed by all|default" is quite helpful.

Answer (score 8):

If you revise your regular expression like this:

```
drupal-6.14/(?=sites(?!/all|/default)).*
             ^^
```

...then it will match all inputs that contain `drupal-6.14/` followed by `sites` followed by *anything other than* `/all` or `/default`. For example:

```
drupal-6.14/sites/foo
drupal-6.14/sites/bar
drupal-6.14/sitesfoo42
drupal-6.14/sitesall
```

Changing `?=` to `?!` to match your original regex simply negates those matches:

```
drupal-6.14/(?!sites(?!/all|/default)).*
             ^^
```

So, this simply means that `drupal-6.14/` now *cannot* be followed by `sites` followed by *anything other than* `/all` or `/default`. So now, *these* inputs will satisfy the regex:

```
drupal-6.14/sites/all
drupal-6.14/sites/default
drupal-6.14/sites/all42
```

But, what may not be obvious from some of the other answers (and possibly your question) is that your regex will also permit *other* inputs where `drupal-6.14/` is followed by anything other than `sites` as well. For example:

```
drupal-6.14/foo
drupal-6.14/xsites
```

**Conclusion:** So, your regex basically says to include *all* subdirectories of `drupal-6.14` *except* those subdirectories of `sites` whose name begins with anything other than `all` or `default`.