# Regex, grab only one instance of each letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a paragraph that's broken up into an array, split at the periods. I'd like to perform a regex on index[i], replacing it's contents with one instance of each letter that index[i]'s string value has.

So; index[i]:"This is a sentence" would return --> index[i]:"thisaenc"

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631468/regex-to-use-each-letter-only-once). But i'm not sure if that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: What regex flaver are you using?  Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Comment: @agent-j - Jquery, added the tag.

Comment: @Jason, what's this got to do with jQuery?

Comment: strictly speaking, a substitution is more than just a regexp. But you should specify your language, the quirks and varieties of regexp engines are legion. Though you'll need one with variable-length negative lookback, I'm almost sure, or find a workaround.

Comment: Does the order of the output characters matter?  You can do my solution below, except with a slightly different negative lookahead (which jscript supports), but characters will be added as if you were reading right-to-left.

Comment: Do you just want all the unique letters that occur in the sentence?

Comment: Empty while loop works in perl: `while ($str =~ s/(\w)(.*)(\1)(.*)/\1\2\4/i) {}` someone just has to strip the spaces and lower the cases somehow in javascript, and rewrite that pattern in javascript and it'll work. I have no idea how to do that :p Oh, none greedy matching not necessary, I'll edit that out. Just made more sense in my head to be none greedy.

Comment: So apparently javascript returns the new string instead of a boolean, um... you can still do it if you just store the string and then have the while condition be if the new replaced string != the old stored string then keep replacing. That's probably more involved than you want though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm pretty sure what you need cannot be achieved using a single regular expression, I offer a more general solution:

```
// collapseSentences(ary) will collapse each sentence in ary 
// into a string containing its constituent chars
// @param  {Array}  the array of strings to collapse
// @return {Array}  the collapsed sentences
function collapseSentences(ary){
  var result=[];
  ary.forEach(function(line){
    var tmp={};
    line.toLowerCase().split('').forEach(function(c){
        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            tmp[c]++;
        }
    });
    result.push(Object.keys(tmp).join(''));
  });
  return result;
}
```

which should do what you want except that the order of characters in each sentence cannot be guaranteed to be preserved, though in most cases it is.

Given:

```
var index=['This is a sentence','This is a test','this is another test'],
    result=collapseSentences(index);
```

result contains:

```
["thisaenc","thisae", "thisanoer"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do this in regex, but here's a very simple function to do it without using regex:

```
function charsInString(input) {
    var output='';
    for(var pos=0; pos<input.length; pos++) {
        char=input.charAt(pos).toLowerCase();
        if(output.indexOf(char) == -1 && char != ' ') {output+=char;}
    }
    return output;
}

alert(charsInString('This is a sentence'));
```

Comment: If you change the two lines like this: 
        `char=input.charAt(pos).toLowerCase();
        if(output.indexOf(char) == -1 && char != ' ') {output+=char;}` it would give the exact desired string.

Comment: @morja -- yes, thanks; I'll edit the answer. (I posted it without testing it or checking it because just as I was finishing I saw @Jason had posted his own answer!)

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w)(?<!.*?\1)
```

This yields a match for each of the right characters, but as if you were reading right-to-left instead.
This finds a word character, then looks ahead for the character just matched.

Comment: If as previously stated JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind, how would this work in the OP's stated environment?

Comment: What regex flavor does that work under?  Lookbehind typically needs to be fixed width, and in your case isn't looking behind anything or actually causing the string to be substituted.

Comment: I answered the question before he answered my request for environment.  Good catch, though.  :-)

Comment: I suppose you could use a positive lookahead, then replace the matches with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i managed:

```
justC = "";
if (color[i+1].match(/A/g)) {justC += " L_A";}
if (color[i+1].match(/B/g)) {justC += " L_B";}
if (color[i+1].match(/C/g)) {justC += " L_C";}
if (color[i+1].match(/D/g)) {justC += " L_D";}
if (color[i+1].match(/E/g)) {justC += " L_E";}
else {color[i+1] = "L_F";}
```

It's not exactly what my question may have lead to belive is what i wanted, but the printout for this is what i was after, for use in a class: `<span class="L_A L_C L_E"></span>`

Comment: glad you found a solution that worked for you. I've got absolutely no clue how this relates to the question though!

Comment: Err... match(/A/g) will return the number of times 'A' appears in the target while match(/A/) will return 1 (true) if at least one 'A' occurs. Lose the /g to significantly improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var re = /(.)((.*?)\1)/g;
var str = 'This is a sentence';
x = str.toLowerCase();
x = x.replace(/ /g, '');
while(x.match(re)) {
    x=x.replace(re, '$1$3');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this can be done in one fell regex swoop.  You are going to need to use a loop.

While my example was not written in your language of choice, it doesn't seem to use any regex features not present in javascript.

```
perl -e '$foo="This is a sentence"; while ($foo =~ s/((.).*?)\2/$1/ig)  { print "<$1><$2><$foo>\n"; } print "$foo\n";'
```

Producing:

```
This aenc
```

Comment: Why exactly was the downvoted?  It works and uses regular expression.