# grepping out invalid URIs

Tags: regex, grep, uri

I have dbpedia's NTriple files. Some of them contain non absolute URIs, URI's that don't start with http://. This is causing problem to the parsing.

i.e. i have some triples that have URIs like <www.example.com> instead of <http://www.example.com>

I'd like to grep them out by negating them.

I tried, failing, with grep -v "^(<http)".

Any suggestion?

**Edit**

I probably made my point wrongly. These URI's aren't necessarily at the beginning of the line. That was my mistake in using the '^' operator as NOT.
Also, I want to grep them out, with grep -v.

These are some sample lines:

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Petrodvorets_Watch_Factory> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/homepage> <www.raketa.su> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/ABS_network> <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/homepage> <www.absn.tv> .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle multiple URIs per line the working regex is:

grep -P '<(?!http(s)?:\/\/).*>', to start with.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -P '^(?!<http).*'
```

(?!...) is a negative lookahead
I did not test it so if you that does not work, search the web for
'regex negative lookahead'
that should do the job

Comment: that does indeed not work. I checked out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead) which makes me think your guess is correct. Can't understand what's going on.

Comment: that is strange, i tested it on a file i wrote with <http://....> and <www....> lines and it worked... - maybe you can post a dummy file to test with it?#

Comment: One question, is every url a line or can there be more?
If copy paste your urls as lines (1 url 1 line) and save it to test
>  grep -P '^(?!<http).*' test  <
works.

Comment: Well, that changes alot. Can you just put 1 URL in 1 Line? Doing this would allow you to use the grep command. Atm I do not know a way to do it when 3 URLs are in 1 line... sorry
To move the urls to single lines, i would use VIM:
in edit mode press qa (macro record to 'a') ---
then '0', f_(_ is space), 'x', 'i', 'ENTER', 'ESC', f_(_ is space), 'x', 'i', 'ENTER', f_(_ is space), 'd$', 'j', then 'q' -----

Comment: I found the solution: grep -P '<(?!http).*>'. the '<' defines the beginning of the pattern and is static. Then you define NOT followed by http and closed later. Thanks for getting me started on this one!

Answer (score 0):

"^(<http)" would only match if "<http" is at the beginning of the line. Is that true in your case?