# Ignore a link in my RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a rule that will ignore a particular link in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_",'w\s@]+)$ profile?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_",'w\s@]+)/$ profile?u=$1
```

the code above will redirect any link like http://me.com/you

to http://me.com/profile?u=you

but i want it to ignore the word **contact** so that when the user types me.com/contact

the user goes to the contact page instead of going to me.com/profile?u=contact

thanks, your help will really be appreciated

Comment: This belongs to *regex* and not *php*. Negative lookahead might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead .

Comment: I never new there was any thing like category here

Answer (score 0):

Add this right before the rule to exclude the word:

```
RewriteCond ^((?!contact).+)$
```

Really, you can look it up in a reference.

Comment: [Thu Jun 14 02:26:52 2012] [alert] [client ::1] C:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '!^/webtop$'
[Thu Jun 14 02:26:52 2012] [alert] [client ::1] C:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '!^/webtop$'

Comment: @meakindele what does the log sat this time?

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/.htaccess: Invalid command '^((?!contact).+)$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: do you use apache mod_rewrite? Sure you add `RewriteCond` and not a `RewriteRule`?

Comment: i made a mistake that generated the last error, i have corrected it and now its back to the first error

Comment: an ideal came to my mind ignoring any folder or file name so i use this     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d Thanks