# How do I use regex to ignore strings that have a certain string preceding them?

Tags: c#, regex

I've turned on case insensitivity...

I want to match `abc` anywhere except in `watch?v=xxabcxx` or `tumblr_asdfabcasdf`.

But if I use `(watch\?v=[0-9a-zA-Z]){0}abc` against `watch?v=xxabcxx`, it matches, presumably because the engine fails until it checks `abcxxx` which is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expressions that is called negative look behind (also ahead, depending of the direction you need to look at).  Check the tutorial on "*[Positive and Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*".

You might want also check the question and answer for "*[Regular expression negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead)*".

As an example, take a look at `(watch\?v=.*)(?<!xx)abc`, the part `(?<xx)abc` can be read as *`abc` matches only if the preceding letters do not match with `xx`*, where `(?a)b` is the format to put a condition `a` before apply `b`. Also, the symbol `<` says *look behind* and the exclamation mark `!` is to negate the condition.  I used a generic regular expression, but you can get the idea.

Comment: I can't understand it for the life of me, but thanks for posting

Comment: I added an small example (based in your question) to explain how it works.  I hope this help to understand the tutorial.

Comment: It works! Thanks!
`(?<!watch\?v=[0-9a-zA-Z]*|tumblr_[0-9a-zA-Z]*)abc`