# Javascript Pangram Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, pangram

I am trying to write a REGEX to test for a PANGRAM. I can do it the traditional way, but cannot seem to solve it for more than 90% of my tests with a regular expression.

Input: string

Output: true || false

```
function isPangram(string){ 
   return ___________________.test(string) 
}
```

Test Results so far.

6/10
`/([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z, \s]+)/i`

6/10
`/[a-z]{1}/i`

6/10 `/[a-z]/i`

6/10 `/[a-z]+/i`

9/10 `/a?b?c?d?e?f?g?h?i?j?k?l?m?n?o?p?q?r?s?t?u?v?w?x?y?z/i`
    only failed against `abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz`

6/10 `/[\w.]+/`

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give the ser if tests ?

Comment: so you are trying to use only regex to test Pangram.?? this is going to be hard.

Comment: You just need _something_ in place of `___________________` or another approach will work for you(as in my answer below)?

Comment: Thanks everyone, zerkms answer below passed all  20 tests if you are interested in running it.

Comment: https://exercism.org/tracks/javascript/exercises/pangram/solutions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be a correct answer for the challenge:

```
function isPangram(string){ 
   return /(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)(?=.*f)(?=.*g)(?=.*h)(?=.*i)(?=.*j)(?=.*k)(?=.*l)(?=.*m)(?=.*n)(?=.*o)(?=.*p)(?=.*q)(?=.*r)(?=.*s)(?=.*t)(?=.*u)(?=.*v)(?=.*w)(?=.*x)(?=.*y)(?=.*z)./i.test(string) 
}
```

It uses lookaheads with every letter to check that they are somewhere in the passed string.

Answer (score 28):

1. Convert the string to lowercase
2. Use regex to extract all the unique alphabets from string
3. Check if the no of unique alphabets are 26

Code:

```
function isPangram(string) {
    var regex = /([a-z])(?!.*\1)/g;
    return (string.match(regex) || []).length === 26;
}
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/qV4nH4/1)

```js
var regex = /([a-z])(?!.*\1)/g;

function check() {
  var val = document.getElementById('text').value.toLowerCase();

  alert(val.match(regex).length == 26);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" />

<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Check the question - it provides the template for the function. So you cannot put arbitrary js, the answer must be a regex only.

Comment: Technically it still does not qualify the requirements. The challenge requires you to only substitute the `_______` part and not modify anything else.

Comment: this is an awesome approach, and also passed another round of testing. But it did not pass for  :     ' AbCdEfGhIjKlM zYxWvUtSrQpOn'  or   ' How quickly daft jumping zebras vex.'  Tricky

Comment: @Vontei The both strings are PANGRAMS and it's showing as _true_ when given input to the above demo, it's working as expected. Isn't it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar it does not answer the question asked though :-D

Comment: Could you explain the regex that you used?

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for **Non-RegExp** Solution

```js
const isPangram = (string) => 
     new Set(string.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]/g)).size === 26;

console.log(isPangram("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));  //true
console.log(isPangram("The Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the lazy dog")); //true
```

Answer (score 3):

As a single regex:

```
/(?:(?=(.*?([a-z]))(?!.*\2))\1){26}/i
```

Test it at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XONCDK/1).

A breakdown:

```
/
  (?:               // non-capturing group
    (?=             // look-ahead assertion

      (.*?([a-z]))  // match a letter, preceded by as few characters as possible
      (?!.*\2)      // assert that this letter does not appear in the remainder of the string
                    // (in aggregate, this will find the last occurrence of each letter)

    )\1             // actually match that group (this is done to prevent backtracking)
  ){26}             // match 26 times (once for each letter)
/i                  // match case-insensitively
```

If the regex engine you're using supports [atomic grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Possessive_matching) (e.g. PCRE), this can be written somewhat more concisely:

```
/(?>.*?([a-z])(?!.*\1)){26}/i
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eiktkE/1).

Answer (score 3):

**using for..of loop & includes:**

```
function isPangram(sentence) {
let lowerCased = sentence.toLowerCase();
for (let char of 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') {
    if (!lowerCased.includes(char)) {
        return false;
     }
  }
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a string, detect whether or not it is a pangram. **Return True if it is, False if not**. Ignore numbers and punctuation. [adding case-insensitivity based on the regex code provided by @Tushar]

```js
//Detect Pangram
function isPangram(string){
// character set capturing group with negative lookahead
  let regex = /([a-z])(?!.*\1)/gi;
  return (string.match(regex)).length === 26;
}

console.log(isPangram("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."));// true
console.log(isPangram("This is not a pangram."));// false
console.log(isPangram("Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs."));// true
console.log(isPangram("This isn't a pangram!"));// false
console.log(isPangram("Detect Pangram"));// false
console.log(isPangram("How quickly daft jumping zebras vex."));// true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isPangram(input) {
  if(input.length < 26) {
    return false;
  }
  const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  return Array.from(new Set(input.toLowerCase().split('').filter(i => i.trim()))).sort().join('') === letters;  
}

console.log(isPangram("The String is abcdefghijklumnopqrstvwxyz")); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [Tushar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32557405/22864457), I noticed that their regex was only matching one case in their code; but there was more script in their HTML file. Using `[a-zA-Z]` regex to match lowercase and uppercase would mean that a pangram has to have 52 letters. So, to correct this, we can still make it 26 by lowercasing the string before checking it, just using the [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method.

Also, I was thinking that you came from [Exercism's Pangram exercise](https://exercism.org/tracks/javascript/exercises/pangram), because you mentioned that there were ten tests and that the top solution didn't pass. I made sure this one passes.

#### The code

```js
const isPangram = string =>
  (string.toLowerCase().match(/([a-z])(?!.*\1)/g) ?? []).length === 26;
```

1. Convert string to lowercase
2. Match for regex
3. If the match is falsy, then use empty array instead
4. Check if the length is 26, which is the same as if it's a pangram

#### The RegEx

`([a-z])(?!.*\1)`

1. First capturing group matches for every letter from a to z
2. Second group uses a [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749956/22864457) to determine if any character does not match group one

#### Also

Oh, and by the way, I used the [nullish coalescing operator `(??)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). Basically, it's `||` but specifically for `null` or `undefined`

You can think about it as `!=` vs `||` and `!==` vs `??` being the same; respectively that the first check for falsy and the second checks if it's strictly inequal.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const isPangram = (string) => 
     new Set(string.toLowerCase().match(/[a-z]/g)).size === 26;

console.log(isPangram("This is not a pangram."));  //false
console.log(isPangram("The Quick Brown Fox Jumps over the lazy dog")); //true
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and add a little textual explanation to it: Why and how does it work and what makes it differ from the other answers given.

Answer (score -3):

```
function isPangram(string){

  let lc = string.toLowerCase()
 let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

   return alphabet.split("").filter(c => lc.indexOf(c) === -1).length === 0;
}
```

1. Lower case the string
2. Create a string with the alphabet
3. split the alphabet
4. Using filter() with a mini function that will verify that there are 0 false statements in it (filter it so there is 0 (zero) false statement (-1) in the new array that the filter method creates ".lengeth === 0" makes sure there is no false statement
   )

Comment: OP is asking about using a RegEx (Regular Expression), not how to do this problem in general.

Comment: Yes, but I saw a Non-Regex solution above mine I thought would be useful to give him a different solution in that sense. But thank you anyway!