# Exclude Jenkins jobs from view with regular expression

Tags: regex, jenkins

We're using regular expressions to include jobs in our views for Jenkins. 
At the moment the regular expression for the "example"-view is `example_(.+)`.

However we just added a new project called "example_example2" and now the jobs from this project also appear in the "example" view.
Is there any regular expression to exclude the "example_example2"-jobs from the "example"-view? I have been trying to use `^` but no success.

Could you help me out?

Comment: Try `example_(?!example2$)(.+)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match `example_` not followed with `example2` followed with the end of string position using a negative lookahead:

```
example_(?!example2$)(.+)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In case you need to anchor the pattern add `^` at the start. `.+` will match any 1 or more characters other than line break chars up to the end of the line.

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/RiFsOm/1).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answerand the regex demo. I expanded the expression to `example_(?!example2.+$)(.+)` to also exclude example_example2_example3. According to the demo it should work. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working in Jenkins. Any ideas? EDIT: Nevermind, i just needed to uncheck the boxes for the jobs in the view. Thank you for your help!

Comment: To  avoid matching any string with `example2` after `example_`, you may just remove the `$` in my regex: `example_(?!example2)(.+)`. You say it does not match in *Regular Expression Job Filter*? Is `example_` at the start of the input? Prepend the pattern with `.*` then.

Comment: > To avoid matching any string with example2 after example_, you may just remove the $ in my regex: example_(?!example2)(.+).   True, thank you.

Comment: Yes, because `$` is the [end-of-string anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1603/anchor-characters-dollar/5199/match-a-letter-at-the-end-of-a-line-or-string).

Comment: @MarceloFilho What "doesn't work"? The current solution works for OP problem, namely excluding a match if there is `example2` right after `example_` at the end of the string. What is your problem?