# Regex for Page Filtering in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, expression

I'm trying to use GA to filter out certain URL pages.  I need to distinguish between pages like this:

```
www.example.com/hotel/hotelfoofoo
```

and this:

```
www.example.com/hotel/hotelfoofoo/various-options-go-here?lots-of-other-stuff-follows
```

I'm new to regex, so I know very little, but am basically trying to capture URL pages that begin with `/hotel/` but do not include any other forward slashes.  Is there a way to write that code?

Comment: can anyone help???  in desperate need.  thank you

Comment: Can you provide more examples of what you want to match and what you don't?

Comment: I want to match visits to the hotel page overview, which for every hotel on the site matches /hotel/hotelname.    But I don't want to include pages where the visitor went on to "select a room", or "check available dates", etc.   Whenever the user does those things, it still begins with /hotel/hotelname but then goes on to include another "/" and various text afterwards.

Comment: Use negative lookahead check like in this question like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead . Simple example: hotelfoofoo(?!/). Not I want be able to help with regexp until you provide 3 different examples of what you want to match and 3 examples of what you don'r

Comment: Just update question with examples.

Comment: Okay, I DO want to include these 3:

/hotel/Hotel-Palace-Berlin-Berlin-Germany
/hotel/The-Ritz-London-London-England
/hotel/Halekulani-Honolulu-HI

I do NOT want to include these 3:

/hotel/Hotel-Palace-Berlin-Berlin-Germany/select-room?cvosrc=partners.trivago.view_deals_lhwde

/hotel/The-Ritz-London-London-England/book?cvosrc=partners.trivago.view_deals_lhwuk

/hotel/Halekulani-Honolulu-HI?pid=APACHalekulani&cvosrc=social_media.facebook.apachalekulani_post

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1) Assuming only alpha numeric + '-' signs allowed in the name of hotel:

```
/hotel/([-\w]+)(?![-\/\w])
```

Note: hotel name would be caught in first group. Idea here - is to capture all digits/letters/underscor/- symbols which are not followed by slash.

2) Assuming white space symbol required to designate url end:

```
/hotel/([^\s/]+)(?=\s)
```

Note: depending on your regexp language some of character should be escaped. For js all "/" should be escaped e.g.: "/"