# how to replace in-between fullstops with comma?

Tags: java, regex, shell

I am trying to replace in-between periods and exclamations i.e.,(.,!) with comma. When I tried, my code replaces all the fullstops(.) with comma(,) but, I dont want to change the ending fullstop.

```
String txt="When I'm bored, I eat. When I'm happy, I eat. When I'm sad, I eat.";

txt = txt.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7f-\\x80-\\xad]", ""); //replaces emojies

//String a=txt.replaceAll("[.!]", ","); //replaces comma or exclamation

System.out.println(txt);
```

OUTPUT WITH LINE COMMENTED OUT:

```
When I'm bored, I eat. When I'm happy, I eat. When I'm sad, I eat.
```

OUTPUT WITH CODE INSTEAD OF COMMENT (`and println(a)`):

```
When I'm bored, I eat, When I'm happy, I eat, When I'm sad, I eat,
```

Comment: Why isn't the period repalced here? ==> `When I'm happy, I eat.`

Comment: If you want to replace all periods/exclamations but the last, that might help:
`String a=txt.replaceAll("([.!] *)\b", ", ");`

Comment: Please show your original string and expected outcome string. In above string, I cant see any "!" marks.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution using any of `bash` utils `sed`/`awk`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749956/1983854):

```
[\.!](?<!$)
```

That is: do replace whenever the dot or exclamation mark occur somewhere not at the end of a string.

```
String a=txt.replaceAll("[\.!](?<!$)", ",");
```

See the expression and how it matches in: http://www.rubular.com/r/L5oSf1aCa5

Answer (score 0):

You can just use substring, do the replace and concatanate it back.

String txt="When I'm bored, I eat. When I'm happy, I eat. When I'm sad, I eat.";

String a=txt.substring(0, java.lang.Math.max(txt.lastIndexOf('.'), txt.lastIndexOf('!')));

a=a.replaceAll("[^\x00-\x7f-\x80-\xad]", ""); //replaces emojies

a=a.replaceAll("[.!]", ",")+txt.substring(java.lang.Math.max(txt.lastIndexOf('.'), txt.lastIndexOf('!')),txt.length()); //replaces comma or exclamation

System.out.println(a);