# How to get this regex include overlapping occurrences, but not too much:-?

Tags: python, regex, overlapping-matches

I want to get all the occurrences of the pattern '[number]' including their context but I can't.

**Here is my code:**

```
import re
text = 'some crap [00][0] some more'
regex = r'\[[0-9]*\]'
regex = '.{0,10}' + regex + '.{0,10}'
occurrences = re.findall(regex, text)
for occ in occurrences print(occ)
```

**What is actually wrong!?**

My code works just as I wish in any case except for when there are two [number] blocks with less than 10 characters in between. where my code gives me one result while I'm looking for two. If I set the regex to include the overlapping occurrences then it will give all the results for different context lengths. I can't set the context length specifically because I want to include the occurrences at the beginning and end of the string.

**What I actually want:**

I prefer a pure regex solution to get me all the occurrences of the mentioned pattern including their context.

If really impossible I'd do fine with a solution that uses the positions and selects a range from the string.

Comment: Can you please provide us with multiple inputs and their expected outputs so that we have a better understanding of what you are looking for?

Comment: [`(?:(?!\[\d*\]).){0,10}\[\d*\](?:(?!\[\d*\]).){0,10}`](https://regex101.com/r/axf8ub/1)?

Comment: @user if you mean '.{0,10}\[(\d+)\].{0,10}' no I'm not because that does not give be the context, that Is only giving me some numbers.

Comment: @ctwheels that worked. thanks a lot:) you are a regex god!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) and [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead).

To fix your issue just change the forth line to:

```
regex = '(?:(?!' + regex + ').){0,10}' + regex + '(?:(?!' + regex + ').){0,10}'
```