# regex last repetition

Tags: regex

I have a string: `0220110000AL0091` and I would like to get back the last `000` for replace by three spaces.
So for: `0220110000AL0091`, I want to replace by `0220110   AL0091`.

I don't know how to apply the regex between the 7th and 11th characters!

Thanks

Comment: What language are you working with? Assuming you mean general repetition, not necessarily three zeros, try `/(.)\1\1(?!\1)/` and replace it with three spaces.

Comment: By matching 6 arbitrary characters before, and then necessary amount zeroes/digits after that …?

Comment: I works with postgres.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749956/7051394).
You will look for a sequence of three zeros, not followed by a zero.

Here is how you could do it in Python (doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> -> `(?!`):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "0220110000AL0091"
>>> re.sub("000(?!0)", "   ", s)
'0220110   AL0091'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect !

Comment: @Rightleg how did you know OP is using python?

Comment: @ctwheels I don't, it's just an example with a common language that I know. Besides, as long as the language supports lookahead assumptions, this regex is likely to work, and if it didn't, I think the negative lookahead would still be the solution.