# Check if keywords with same order exists in a text

Tags: regex, sequence, regex-lookarounds

So we have two types of keywords:

1. Keywords which start with `!`, This keyword should contain in text
2. Keywords which start with `@!`, This keyword shouldn't be seen in text

We want to check if there is **at least one** valid pattern for given keywords. There might be many occurrences of keywords, finding any valid pattern is fine for us.

Example 1:
keywords: ['!A', '!C']
Text:

```
Multiline text ...

A

Some other text

C
```

Expected result: True

Example 2:
keywords: ['!A', '@!B' , '!C']
Text:

```
Multiline text ...

A

Some other text

B
C
```

Expected result: False, since B is placed between A and C

Example 3:
keywords: ['!A', '@!B' , '!C']
Text:

```
Multiline text ...

A

Some other text

B

A

C
```

Expected result: True, since there is no B after second A, and C is after that.

What I've tried so far(without luck):

1. Use regex ( i wasn't able to use [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead) as well)
2. Try to write a recursive function for it

Sample function for method 1:

```
def contain_keywords(content, keywords):
    content = str(content)
    regex_builder = []
    or_keyword = False
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword.startswith("@!"):
            reg = '[^%s]' % re.escape(keyword[2:])
            regex_builder.append(reg)
        elif keyword.startswith("!"):
            reg = '(%s)' % re.escape(keyword[1:])
            regex_builder.append(reg)

    pattern = r'.*%s.*' % ('([\s\S])*'.join(regex_builder))
    res = re.search(pattern, content)
    return res is not None
```

Sample function for method 2:

```
def contain_keywords2(content, keywords, offset=0, keyword_index=0):
    content = str(content)
    valid_pattern = True
    or_keyword = False

    if keyword_index >= len(keywords) or offset >= len(content):
        return True

    for keyword_index, keyword in enumerate(keywords[keyword_index:]):
        keyword = keyword.strip()
        if keyword.startswith("@!"):
            reg = keyword[2:]
            location = content[offset:].find(reg)
            if location != -1:
                return False
            valid_pattern = contain_keywords2(content, keywords, offset=offset, keyword_index=keyword_index+1)
            if not valid_pattern:
                return False
        elif keyword.startswith("!"):
            reg = keyword[1:]
            location = content[offset:].find(reg)
            print(location + offset)
            if location == -1:
                return False
            if keyword_index + 1 >= len(keywords):
                break
            valid_pattern = contain_keywords2(content, keywords, offset=offset + location + len(reg), keyword_index=keyword_index+1)
            if not valid_pattern:
                return False
    return valid_pattern
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered it, I'll post my solution:

```
def contain_keywords2(content_text, keywords, offset=0, keyword_index=0):

    or_keyword = False

    if keyword_index >= len(keywords) or offset >= len(content_text):
        return True

    for loop_keyword_index, keyword in enumerate(keywords[keyword_index:]):
        keyword = keyword.lstrip()
        if keyword.startswith("@!"):
            reg = keyword[2:]
            # Don't look whole file, just search it in at last 10 lines:
            # If you want to search all over the file, remove these 3 lines (including pos_of_tens_line at location ...)
            pos_of_tens_line = findnth(content_text[offset:], '\n', 10)
            if pos_of_tens_line == -1:
                pos_of_tens_line = len(content_text)

            location = content_text.find(reg, offset, offset + pos_of_tens_line)

            if location != -1:
                return False
            return contain_keywords2(content_text, keywords, offset=offset,
                                     keyword_index=keyword_index + loop_keyword_index + 1)
        elif keyword.startswith("!"):
            reg = keyword[1:].strip()

            for keyword_positions in list(find_all(content_text[offset:], reg)):
                valid_pattern = contain_keywords2(content_text, keywords,
                                                  offset=(offset + keyword_positions + len(reg)),
                                                  keyword_index=(keyword_index + loop_keyword_index + 1))
                if valid_pattern:
                    return True
            return False
        elif keyword.startswith('|!'):
            or_keyword = True
            break

    if or_keyword:
        for keyword in keywords:
            if keyword.startswith('|!'):
                if keyword[2:] in content_text:
                    return True
    return False
```