# Using jdeps with REGEX

Tags: java, regex, jdeps

I'm able to get the list of dependencies using jdeps:
`jdeps myjar.jar` works fine.

Tried excluding a particular package in the output:
`jdeps -f 'java.io' myjar.jar` - this excludes the package `java.io` from the output

Finally, i would like to exclude all packages that starts with the name "java" using regex:

- `jdeps -f 'java' myjar.jar` -> didn't work (does not filter 'java' packages)
- `jdeps -f '/java/i' myjar.jar`-> didn't work (does not filter 'java' packages)
- `jdeps -f '^java' myjar.jar` -> didn't work (does not filter 'java' packages)

Can someone help me to filter all the packages that match a given pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Try **Negative Lookahead** operator [!?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead)

The regex looks like this: `^(?!java)` (returning only when line doesn't start with *java*)

The final code looks like this: `jdeps -f '^(?!java)' myjar.jar`