# Regular expression to match only code lines that are uncommented

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need a regex to match only code lines that are not commented.

For example:

```
// Messagebox(a,b,c, mb_ok);
Messagebox(a,b,c, mb_ok|mb_taskmodal);
Messagebox(a,b,c, mb_ok);
```

I have regex to match 1and 3. Now I want to filter out the commented lines too. Final regex should match only line 3.
Is that possible only with regex?

Regex used to match 1 and3: https://regexr.com/51mjh

```
(MessageBox\(\s*.*,.*,.*,\s*)(?!.*MB_TASKMODAL)
```

Conditions:

a. MessageBox API that takes 4 parameters.

b. Last parameter should not contain MB_TASKMODAL.

c. The line should not be one commented out.

Comment: What regex flavor?  Do you have the option to exclude lines via regex (e.g. `grep -v`) or only include lines?

Answer (score 1):

You avoid `//`-commented lines with:

```
^(?!\/\/).*
```

Explanation (also [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dQbFiq/1)):

- `^` Start of a line
- `(?!\/\/)` Not a literal leading `//` (this is a [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749956/519360))
- `.*` Any number of any character (to skip blank lines, change to `.+`)

If you're worried about leading white space, use `^(?!\s*\/\/).*` instead.

---

Now to get to the part about matching only line three.

If you want to match more than the absence of a comment, change the `.*` to what you want to match. I'm not exactly sure what you want to match and not match, so this is a guess based on what intentions I can glean from your attempt.

```
^(?!\/\/).*\bMessagebox\((?!.*\bmb_taskmodal\b).*
```

This has the aforementioned exclusion for commented lines, then it matches `Messagebox(` following a non-word character (or nothing) *except* if it is eventually followed by `mb_taskmodal` as a full word, then anything else.

I'm using `\b` a bit here. That just means exactly one side (either before or after the `\b`) has a word character (a letter, number, or underscore) and the other side has a non-word character. The "b" stands for "[word] boundary". Escaped non-word characters are always literals, so `\(` and `\/` are a literal `(` and `/` respectively.

Note that this regex will still match `Messagebox(a,b,c, mb_ok); // |mb_taskmodal);`. Resolving that is nontrivial since the inline comment indicator is two characters. I can answer that too, but hopefully you don't need it.

---

Solutions with grep:

```sh
$ grep -v '^//' FILENAME                            # discard comments
$ grep -v '^//' FILENAME |grep -vFw 'mb_taskmodal'  # also discard mb_taskmodal
```

Grep's `-v` flag inverts the match. `-F` disables regexes and uses a plain text match (faster), and `-w` requires word boundaries around the query (the same as `\bmb_taskmodal\b` assuming GNU grep without `-F`).

---

Extended Regular Expression (ERE) comment-filtering solution (no lookaround):

(If you're using grep, consider `grep -v '^//' FILENAME` instead)

```
^(.?$|[^\/]{2}|[^\/]\/|\/[^\/]).*
```

Explanation (also [at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dQbFiq/3)):

- `^` Start of a line
- `(…)` Capture group (PCRE can inhibit capturing with `(?:…)` instead) containing *either*

  - Alternation one

    - `.?` Any character, zero or one time (change to `..?` to skip blank lines)
    - `$` End of line
  - Alternation two

    - `[^\/]{2}` Any character except a `/`, twice
  - Alternation three

    - `[^\/]` Any character except a `/`
    - `\/` A literal `/`
  - Alternation four (order is swapped)

    - `\/` A literal `/`
    - `[^\/]` Any character except a `/`
- `.*` Any number of any character (including zero, required by alternation one)

This will match a blank line or a line like `/` or `j` or a longer non-comment line.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten the pattern a bit and make use of a negated character class `[^,]` matching any char except a comma, followed by matching the comma. If you group that part, it can be repeated 3 times using a quantifier `{3}`

If the capturing group is the only match, you can also omit it.

As already answered, you could use a negative lookahead to check if the line does not start with `//` and perhaps add `\s*` if there can be possible whitespace chars before it or use `[\S\r\n]*` to match whitespace chars without the newlines.

**Note** that there are also other ways to add comments, which do not have to occur at the start of the line.

```
^(?![^\S\r\n]*//)[^\S\r\n]*MessageBox\(\s*(?:[^,]*,){3}\s*(?!.*MB_TASKMODAL)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YpxdtL/1)

Comment: There is no difference between `^(?!\s*//)MessageBox` and `^MessageBox` since `(?!…)` is zero-width; it says "the next characters cannot be 0+ spaces and then two slashes" but then you specify the next characters must be "MessageBox" which already prevents the comment from matching.

Comment: @AdamKatz Ah yes of course :-), I forgot to add it before the match itself. Updated.