# str.replace unless string is followed by certain text

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, replace

**Revision of prior question:**

How can I replace all ", " (i.e. comma then space) with "_" except when ", " (comma then space) is followed by the word "LLC" or "Inc" (then do nothing)?

**I want to change:**

1. "TEXAS ENERGY MUTUAL, LLC, BOBBY GILLIAM, STEVE PEREIRA and ANDY STITT"
2. "Grape, LLC, Andrea Gray, Jack Smith"
3. "Stephen Winters, Apple, pear, Inc, Sarah Smith"

**To this:**

1. "TEXAS ENERGY MUTUAL, LLC_BOBBY GILLIAM_STEVE PEREIRA_ANDY STITT"
2. "Grape, LLC_Andrea Gray_Jack Smith"
3. "Stephen Winters_Apple_pear, Inc_Sarah Smith"

I thought it would start with some variation of the code below but I cannot figure out the except conditions.

df['Column_Name'] = df['Column_Name'].str.replace(', ','_')
Cheers!

Comment: You can search for `, ` and `, LLC` and `,  lnc` indices and take only what not intersect with the 2 last options. Well recommended convert the indices to `set`

Comment: Is the number of spaces fixed to one after `,`? Or can there be 0, 1 or 2 or more spaces? `, (?!Inc|LLC)` won't work then, else, it is a solution (a word boundary might be handy here, but it depends on the actual requirements).

Comment: Try `replace(r',(?!\s+(?:LLC|Inc)\b)\s+', '_')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace using a regex with a [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead):

```
#no idea why Inc|LLC or LLC|Inc will skip the first
df['Column_Name'].str.replace(', (?!=|Inc|LLC)', '_')
```

Output:

```
0    TEXAS ENERGY MUTUAL, LLC_BOBBY GILLIAM_STEVE P...
1                    Grape, LLC_Andrea Gray_Jack Smith
2          Stephen Winters_Apple_pear, Inc_Sarah Smith
Name: ColumnName, dtype: object
```

Comment: This doesn't add the "_".

Comment: @Andrew is that the case in the output I've shown here? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Andrew Then why do you post another question? Fix it here.

Comment: @Andrew I'm not seeing what I'm missing. When I use your new input, it produces exactly what you're expecting. I need you to clarify *"this doesn't add the _"*

Comment: Well, there's no need to accept the answer unless you find it helpful... but `', (?!=|Inc|LLC)'` is a regex using a negative lookahead assertion, that is: `, ` followed by anything that is not `Inc` or `LLC`. `(?!=...)` is the *negative* lookahead, saying followed by something that is not `...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use python regex module [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for with the pattern `, (?!Inc|LLC)` to find all occurrence of  `,`  without following `Inc` or `LLC`

```py
import re

strings = ["Banana, orange", "Grape, LLC", "Apple, pear, Inc"]

[re.sub(", (?!Inc|LLC)",'_',string) for string in strings]
#['Banana_orange', 'Grape, LLC', 'Apple_pear, Inc']
```

Comment: If LLC was not in the end of the string, it will not work. Not sure if that must happen by the little examples

Answer (score 0):

the simple way:

```
def replace(str):
   x = str.split(', ')
   buf = x[0]
   for i in range(1, len(x)): 
      if x[i].startswith('LLC'):
         buf += ', ' + x[i]
      elif x[i].startswith('Inc'):
         buf += ', ' + x[i]
      else:
         buf += '_' + x[i]
   return buf
```

and then try `replace('a, b, LLC, d')`

Comment: What do you mean: "replace('a, b, LLC, d')"

Comment: we define a function `def replace(str)`; try it to test our implementation ...