# What does "(?!$)" inside a regexp mean?

Tags: regex

In [a section of Sevelte tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings), there's a piece of code like this:

```
view = pin ? pin.replace(/\d(?!$)/g, '•') : 'enter your pin';
```

I know `\d` means a digit, but can't figure out what `(?!$)` means.

(And because it's composed of all punctuation, I can't manage to google for an explanation.)

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `\d` matches all digits
- `(?!something)` means 'Negative Lookahead' for *something*
- `$` matches the end of a string

So when `\d(?!$)` is used, it matches all digits before the last character

In this string:

> $$//www12.example@news.com<~>998123000dasas00--987

This will be matched (7 will not because it is the last character):

> 129981230000098

Referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749956/13890583)
and [Regex Cheat Sheet](https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 1):

`(?!$)` Is a negative lookahead stipulation, where `(?!)` declares the negative lookahead and `$` is what that the expression is "looking ahead" for (in this case, an end anchor).

A negative lookahead is an inverse of a positive lookahead, so it will be more intuitive to understand if you know what a positive lookahead is first: A digit followed by a positive lookahead `\d(?=$)` basically looks for anything that would be matched by `\d$` but does not return the part inside the lookahead stipulation when returning a match. `\d(?=$)` will match any digit that is directly behind the end of the string. A *negative* lookahead will simply match every digit that is NOT directly behind the end of the string instead, ergo using `\d(?!$)` and replacing matches with a * basically turns every digit in the string into a `*` except for the last one.

For the sake of being thorough, you should know that `(?<=)` is a positive lookbehind that looks for matches in the characters immediately *before* the given token instead of *after*, and `(?<!)` is a negative lookbehind.

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com) and [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com) are fantastic resources to use when you are learning regex, because you can insert a regular expression you don't understand and get a piece-by-piece explanation of an expression you don't understand and test strings in real time to experiment with what the expression captures and what it doesn't. Even if the built-in explanations don't make sense, you can still use them in situations like this to find out what something is called so you can search for it.