# JavaScript replace with an exception string

Tags: javascript, html, exception, replace

I have the following html tag (which is custom):

```html
<meltdown-code data-lang="HTML">
    <span><br>
        <p>Hi</p><br>
    </span><br>
</meltdown-code>
```

Simple enough. Now, I'm trying to make the HTML tags show as plain text, instead of being rendered as a separate element. To do that, I am replacing all the `<` with `&lt;`, and all the `>` with `&gt;`

```js
tagHTML.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
```

**The problem: This also replaces the `<br>` tags, which doesn't create a new line. Here is the solution, in a perfect world:**

```js
tagHTML.replace(/</g, '&lt;', {exceptions: '<br>'})
```

Obviously, that's not how it works. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [negative lookaheads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749956/18244921)!

Comment: @caTS, thanks for your instant reply! I will check them out and get back to you

Comment: @caTS, sorry... I'm not sure I understand. I'm not really good with regex. Would you mind explaining it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative lookahead for `<br>` before matching `<`.

```js
const text = `<meltdown-code data-lang="HTML">
    <span><br>
        <p>Hi</p><br>
    </span><br>
</meltdown-code>`;

const output = text.replace(/(?!<br>)<([^>]+)>/g, '&lt;$1$gt;');
console.log(output);
```

```html
<code></code>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! There's no way I would have been able to write that Regex on my own lol. I'll accept when i can :D

Comment: @Anye Relevant comic: https://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/02/24/coder-on-the-verge-of-extinction/?

Comment: @caTS My first time working with Regex 