# Join multiple complex regex queries with pipe

Tags: regex

If I use this regex:

```
^((?!^aa$).)*$
```

it works as expected: deselects 'aa' at the line start. But it doesn't if I try to combine it with a similar one:

```
^((?!^aa$).)*$|^((?!^ss$).)*$
```

Can anyone explain why, please?

I tried using both regex group kinds, escape slashes the possible ways, google the question a lot, and read many regex docs. But this is too complicated for me yet.

Comment: Because `|` it is not a pipe in regex it is just equivalent of boolean OR

Comment: Ok, a vertical line, OR... but anyway, it combines successfully the regular versions of patterns if they are not as complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disallow `aa` and `ss` an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) inside a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can be used at [`^` start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```
^(?!aa$|ss$).*
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ropOhi/1) - This will [prevent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749956/5527985) matching any of the defined options.
A lookahead is a *zero-length* assertion that can be used at a any position in a string.