# Replace certain values, but also exclude

Tags: ansible

I have this dummy configuration file:

```ini
something.ok.user.username=abc
something.ok.user.password=def
another_value.log_location=/somewhere
something.ok.whoop.user.username=wh
something.ok.whoop.user.password=asdf
something.ok.user.username=username1
something.ok.user.password=passwoordddd01
something.ok.w.user.username=mygreatuser
something.ok.w.user.password=whocares
something.ok.user.username=yeah
something.ok.user.password=apassword
something.ok.busuiness.user.username=someuser
something.ok.busuiness.user.password=example
```

I want to replace all the values of the username/passwords in this configuration file.  Right now, I have this Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: replace all occurrences of username and password in config file
  replace:
    path: /tmp/file.conf
    regexp: '^(something\.ok.*user\.{{ item.1.regexp }}=).*'
    replace: '\g<1>{{ item.1.replace }}'
  loop:
    - regexp: username
      replace: someone
    - regexp: password
      replace: somepass
```

This works great and as expected. Ansible replaces all the set usernames with `someone`, and all passwords with `somepass`.

The issue: there are some username/passwords which Ansible has to skip replacing. For example, the username/password line containing `something.ok.whoop` and `something.ok.busuiness` must not be changed.
So, these four lines must be skipped:

```ini
something.ok.whoop.user.username=wh
something.ok.whoop.user.password=asdf
something.ok.busuiness.user.username=someuser
something.ok.busuiness.user.password=example
```

My idea was to have a skip list, containing 'whoop' and 'busuiness', set in a variable as a list, e.g.

```yaml
vars:
  skip_list:
    - whoop
    - busuiness
```

Is this even possible using the replace module, or is there a better method to achieve this?

Comment: I would assume you probably know about it, at this point, but templating would probably be a better idea. Also, is there really so much `something.ok.*.user.password` that you cannot have a whitelist of them and use a simpler replace instead of going with a blacklist and probably a more complex negative lookahead regex?

Comment: @ U880D, it is supposed to not make sense :). yeah, that might occur three times, but i don't care about that value. only the one with an specific identifier in it.
@β.εηοιτ.βε templating isn't possible. the idea is that i'm replacing usernames/password in a config file which is old/outdated and manually edited 1000 times. there are files like this across a lot of machines.

Comment: You could write a one of a time playbook to fetch the existing config files and template it from there. I know it is tedious work, though so it all depends the effort / timespan of those managed nodes.

Comment: Ah right right. I can also just use the shell module, or upload a shell script which does the work ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *[negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead)* in your regular expression for this.

A negative lookahead is structured this way:

```
(?!regex_of_what_you_don_t_want_to_match)
```

So, in your case, you possibly want:

```
(?!\.(whoop|business))
```

Which you can definitely obtain from your list:

```
(?!\.({{ skip_list | join("|") }}))
```

---

So, given the task:

```yaml
- name: replace all occurrences of username and password in config file
  replace:
    path: /tmp/file.conf
    regexp: '^(something\.ok(?!\.({{ _skip }})).*\.user\.{{ item.regex }}=).*'
    replace: '\g<1>{{ item.replace }}'
  loop:
    - regex: username
      replace: someone
    - regex: password
      replace: somepass
  vars:
    _skip: "{{ skip_list | join('|') }}"
    skip_list:
      - whoop
      - busuiness
```

And your provided configuration file, you would end up with:

```ini
something.ok.user.username=someone
something.ok.user.password=somepass
another_value.log_location=/somewhere
something.ok.whoop.user.username=wh
something.ok.whoop.user.password=asdf
something.ok.user.username=someone
something.ok.user.password=somepass
something.ok.w.user.username=someone
something.ok.w.user.password=somepass
something.ok.user.username=someone
something.ok.user.password=somepass
something.ok.busuiness.user.username=someuser
something.ok.busuiness.user.password=example
```

Comment: Wauw, works as expected. I have to test it before going into production, but damn, well done!

Answer (score -1):

This is an answer, but most likely not the best answer.

```yaml
- name: read the config file and replace usernames and passwords, including skips
  shell: |
    skip_list=('whoop' 'busuiness')
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      skip=0
      for key in "${skip_list[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$line" == *"something.ok.$key.user.username="* ]] || [[ "$line" == *"something.ok.$key.user.password="* ]]; then
          skip=1
          break
        fi
      done
      if [ "$skip" -eq 0 ]; then
        line=$(echo "$line" | sed -E 's/^(something\.ok.*user\.username=).*/\1someone/')
        line=$(echo "$line" | sed -E 's/^(something\.ok.*user\.password=).*/\1somepass/')
      fi
      echo "$line"
    done </tmp/file.conf > /tmp/file.conf.tmp
    mv /tmp/file.conf.tmp /tmp/file.conf
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```